# Mailgun service - Composer do not run root/super user?

Tags: php, linux, composer, mailgun

При установке `composer` в `linux` получаю `warning`

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
```

Что надо сделать чтобы `Composer` заработал?

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо устанавливать composer от имени обычного пользователя, да и вообще под root-ом сидеть небезопасно.
Ответ есть в самом вопросе `See https://getcomposer.org/root for details`

Comment: ок я воспользовался composer install --no-plugins --no-scripts ... и получил следующую ошибку Invalid argument .... Use "composer require ..." instead to add packages to your composer.json.

Comment: Без composer.json вообще ничего не получится понять

Comment: я устанавливал все как написано в документации и как то composer.json не установился

Comment: composer.json - это файл, в котором описывается то, что нужно установить. Покажите хотя бы команду полностью, что устанавливается?

Comment: я установил - команды отсюда https://getcomposer.org/download/  и написал  - php composer-setup.php --install-dir=bin --filename=composer - mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer